# T-SQL syntax : is '\' the line continue character in t-sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax

See code below. It is not liking my line-continuation character...

Am I doing something wrong?

See code line with text   /*   PROBLEM HERE xxxxx */

I believe I have accurately described the problem but Stack-overflow makes you add more text because it thinks there is not enough description, so sorry that you are reading this sentence. You can skip the rest and jump to the code below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RefreshCustShip3]
AS
BEGIN    /* Begin Proc */
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --Delete from CustShip

    DECLARE @SHIP_TO_NAME VARCHAR(255),
            @A_Cust_No VARCHAR(255),
            @SHIP_TO_ADD_1 VARCHAR(255),
            @SHIP_TO_ADD_2 VARCHAR(255),
            @SHIP_TO_ADD_3 VARCHAR(255),
            @CITY VARCHAR(255),
            @STAT VARCHAR(255),
            @ZIP_Code VARCHAR(255),
            @SHIP_TO_ID VARCHAR(255),
            @COUNTRY VARCHAR(255),
            @ShipId VARCHAR(255),
            @str VARCHAR(1000)

    DECLARE C CURSOR FAST_FORWARD /* read only, forward only */ FOR
        SELECT 
            A#CUST#NO, 
            CUST#NAME AS SHIP#TO#NAME, 
            SOLD#TO#ADD#1 AS SHIP#TO#ADD#1, 
            SOLD#TO#ADD#2 AS SHIP#TO#ADD2, 
            SOLD#TO#ADD#3 AS SHIP#TO#ADD3, 
            SOLD#TO#CITY AS CITY, 
            SOLD#TO#STATE AS [STATE], 
            SOLD#TO#ZIP#CODE AS ZIP#CODE, 
            CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(A#CUST#NO)), LTRIM(RTRIM(SOLD#TO#ADD#1))) AS SHIP#TO#ID, 
            COUNTRY#NAME as Country 
        FROM
            Cust 
        LEFT JOIN
            CustShip ON Cust.A#Cust#No = CustShip.CustNo 
        WHERE 
            CustShip.ShipToID IS NULL

    OPEN C

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @A_Cust_No, @Ship_To_Name, @SHIP_TO_ADD_1, @SHIP_TO_ADD_2, @SHIP_TO_ADD_3, @CITY, @STAT, @ZIP_Code, @SHIP_TO_ID, @Country;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- do work here BEGIN CODE BLOCK
       SELECT @str = 'INSERT INTO CustShip VALUES (' + '''' + @A_Cust_No + '''' + ', ' + '''' +  @Ship_To_Id + '''' + ')'
       EXEC(@str)

       SELECT @str = 'INSERT INTO ShipTo VALUES (' + '''' + @A_Cust_No + '''' + ', '\         /*   PROBLEM HERE xxxxx */
       + '''' +  @Ship_To_Name + '''' + ', '\    /*   PROBLEM HERE xxxxx */
       + '''' +  @Ship_To_Add1 + '''' + ', '\
       + '''' +  @Ship_To_Add2 + '''' + ', '\
       + '''' +  @Ship_To_Add3 + '''' + ', '\
       + '''' +  @City + '''' + ', '\
       + '''' +  @Stat + '''' + ', '\
       + '''' +  @ZIP_Code + '''' + ', '\
       + '''' +  @Ship_To_Id + '''' + ', '\
       + '''' +  @Country + ''''\      
       + ')'
       EXEC(@str)

    CLOSE C;
    DEALLOCATE C;
END     /* End Proc */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements and expressions don't need line continuation characters to be split across lines.

Your `SELECT` statement is already broken across lines.  Other expressions can be split across lines the same way.

You also don't have to do anything special to have a string constant span lines:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(100)
SET @x = 'a
b
c'
+ 'd'
+ 'e'

PRINT @x
```

Also, as @Martin Smith points out, the backslash character can be used to break string literals across lines if you don't want the line feed to be part of the string.

Comment: RE the first line of your answer. yes there is. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-backslash?view=sql-server-2017. Not how the OP is attempting though.